# Sort File Explorer data by text after delimiter

Tags: windows-explorer

I have quite a few .epub files using the naming convention:

Bookname - Author.epub

How do I sort these files in File Explorer by Author

Edit:
I would like to be able to cut and paste all the .epub files by an Author to a folder with the Authors name.

Answer (score 2):

Windows file Explorer does not have the ability split file names into sortable fields. I can think of two options without needing extra software.

**OPTION 1** Search using wild cards, for example if the Author with want is "Jane Something", you can use explorer to search for `* - Jane*`,  however the files will still be sorted using the book title and not author.

**OPTION 2** Use a PowerShell script to do the heavy lifting

1. Copy and paste the text below into Notepad (not word)
2. Save it as `SORT_BY_AUTHOR.ps1` in the same folder as your .epub files
   **Make sure to change the** *type* **from** `Text Document (*.txt)` **to** `All Files (*.*)`
3. Double click the file in the folder and it will generate a .CSV file for you, sorted by author.

```
<#
  SORT_BY_AUTHOR.ps1

  Generates a list of books sorted by author from a directory of files
  with a naming convention of <BookTitle> - <BookAuthor>
#>
$Delimiter = " - "

$Books = Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { 
    $SplitName = $_.BaseName -Split $Delimiter
    [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        Title = $SplitName[0]
        Author = $SplitName[1]
        File = $_.Name
    }   
}

$ExportFile = "_ByAuthor-" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm") + ".csv"
$Books | Export-Csv -Path $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation
Start $ExportFile
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is easier than doing **Copy path**, pasting into Excel doing **Text to Columns** and **Sorting**. I have edited my question with the reason I am asking. +10 for effort.